# Jersey Client 3.1.1 InjectionManagerFactory not found

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish

I am using Jersey Client 3.1.1 to post a JSON object to a REST API, but I am encountering an issue that is known from the 2.x Jersey version: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found`.

There are many questions about this exception which was introduced in later 2.3.x versions. The solution was to add *jersey-hk2* as a dependency. However, this doesn't seem to solve the problem for 3.x, and its one of those issues where there are so many hits regarding 2.x version that I can't  find anything regarding 3.x. I was using jersey-hk2:3.1.1, but I have to now use the 3.x version because I am running Servlet 5.0. / Tomcat 10.

According to the latest Jersey 3.x docs, the following dependency should be used, which pulls in jersey-hk2:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, I am still facing the same issue even after ensuring the version compatibility.

EDIT 1: the exception occurs when I call `request()` on my `JerseyWebTarget`

```
Builder builder = myWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
```

The exception occurs inside `ClientConfig$State.initRuntime()` when it invokes `InjectionManager injectionManager = Injections.createInjectionManager()`

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem. Can you show us a POM and some code which are a [mre]?

Comment: For your reference I am using v3.1.0 of `jakarta.ws.rs-api`. And I am using v3.1.1 of `jersey-client`, `jersey-hk2` and `jersey-media-json-jackson`. I am not using `jersey-cdi1x` - but it looks as if that should work also (for my code, anyway - but my code may be quite different from yours...).

Comment: I'll try to create a simple example, but I can tell you the exception is thrown from  JerseyWebTargetBuilder in private static JerseyInvocation.Builder onBuilder(JerseyInvocation.Builder builder)

Comment: I can recreate your error - but only if I do not explicitly include `jersey-hk2` in my POM. What happens if you remove `jersey-cdi1x` and use `jersey-hk2` (version 3.1.1) instead? It sounds as if you may have already tried that in a previous iteration... but worth another try? Otherwise, please share your POM.

Comment: You are right. When I switched cdi1x back to hk2 it is now working. I must have had some other  conflict in my pom when I started this that was causing the error initially that lead me to switching it to cdi1x. Thank you for confirming!